# Can we write a function in SSRS globally

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Im currently using SSRS-2008R2. I've an scenario where i have to maintain the External image as a logo for each reports we have. Not, only that, we have our custom date formats that what we should change according to the Date Type users define in an asp.net application.

There are lot of things we have to do on every report. Thats my problem.
Following is the one of them Im currently sharing as example :
Currently i maintain the following function for each reports i've:

```
Public Function GetLogoImage() As String
    Dim ImageLogoURL As String
    if Globals!ReportServerUrl is nothing then
        ImageLogoURL = "http://localhost/ReportServer" + "?%2fImages%2fLogo"
    else
        ImageLogoURL = Globals!ReportServerUrl + "?%2fImages%2fLogo"
    Return ImageLogoURL 
End Function
```

I hope, i asked question clearly. Im newbie in SO.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of functions that you wish to apply to multiple reports and you're not willing to copy them to every single one of them, you can create an external library and then add it as a reference to every report.

This is quite simple to do and there's lot of documentation around the web.[You can start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159238%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). You will, however, have to maintain this external library but if you have a lot of code, I personally think this is a much better solution.

If you want to have a predefined layout, you may want to consider having a master report and then include other reports as sub-report objects, but you'll lose some flexibility design wise.

Answer (score -1):

Since the accepted answer is more of a comment and the link provided is broken, i'll provide my answer for people who might need a quick guide on how to use custom code in ssrs:

1. In Design view, right-click the design surface outside the border of the report and click Report Properties.
2. Click Code.
3. In Custom code, type the code. Errors in the code produce warnings when the report runs.

Once you press ok, to call the function that you saved you just need to right click on a cell, select "Expression" and paste in the following string: `Code.GetLogoImage`

More detailed source [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx).

Comment: How this is adding that Code in Global name-space? I was actually looking to put that Function in one place and re-use the same from all reports that we may have in a report project or even from different report project.